# Convert birthday to age using a specific end date 01/01/1998

Tags: r

```
library(eeptools)
x <- as.Date(c(01/01/1998, 'BirthDate'))
age_calc(x[1],x[2]) # default is age in months
```

Want to have the age in years between an initial age in days/month/years to the date 01/01/1998. I have more than 52000 birthdates ?

Hey, it still not working : as.numeric(01/01/1998 - BirthDate)/365.25 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'BirthDate' not found Traceback

Answer (score 1):

Some `base R` possibilities could be:

```
as.numeric(format(x, "%Y")) - as.numeric(format(bday, "%Y"))

[1] 38 28

as.numeric(x - bday)/365.25

[1] 38.00137 28.00000
```

Sample data:

```
x <- as.Date("01/01/1998", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
bday <- as.Date(c("01/01/1960", "01/01/1970"), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Hey, it still not working : as.numeric(01/01/1998 - BirthDate)/365.25
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'BirthDate' not found
Traceback: